# What is the best Approach to keep the data between Database and A text file Synchronized?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently , I'm writing a web application based on mysql and Php .

The thing is , the data in one of the tables should also be written to a text file to allow some process on the system to read from it .

All operations in the database are easy to perform  unlike the text file when I have to update a specific value in one of the lines I have to write a function like this one:

```
function extendSrv($username,$duration,$fileDir)
{
    $date = "enddate=";
    $date .= setExpireDate($duration); //using some other function
    $Read = file($fileDir);

    foreach ( $Read as $LineNum => $line) {
        $LineParts = explode(' ',$line);
        if ( $LineParts[1] == $username ) {
            $LineParts[4] = $date;
            $Read[$LineNum] = implode(' ',$LineParts);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    file_put_contents($fileDir,$Read,LOCK_EX);
}
```

So, Is what I'm doing correct to separate the database and text file modifications or is there another better approach to deliver the data from the database to the process ?

P.S:  I don't have control on the process other than including the text file in the config !

Regards

Comment: What is the text file used for? Can't you just fetch the data from the database and create it "on-the-fly" when you need it? If you for some reason can't do that, or if the file is huge, you could simply regenerate the file from scratch (replace the existing file) when the database is updated, instead of manipulating the existing one.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you mean like creating a function to fetch data from the database and then empty the file and write all the data back again to the text file ?  if so ,do you think this is an optimal solution specially if multiple users are using the same file?

Comment: @M.Eriksson the text file is formatted in a way that is readable by the process .

Comment: Might you use sqlite to generate a db file, which might match you file format.

Comment: Since we don't know the size of the data, what you need to do with it, how much performance it takes, how the file is used, how often the data gets updated etc, it's pretty hard to say what an "optimal" solution would be. But updating the database and modify the existing file the way you're doing doesn't seem optimal in any situation I can think of. Btw, your last comment didn't really tell us anything.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul using sqlite can i form example treat the text file and perform updates like a database file ?

Comment: @M.Eriksson how big is the file ? it will grow with time so yeah the size is unknown and how frequently the data will be update ? it depends on when the users will login and made changes so yeah all these things are unknown

Comment: @ElapsedSoul - What problem would SQLite solve? That's just another database. If they are going to store some modified data, why not just create a table for it in their existing database? That would make more sense than introducing another database engine (which will also have worse performance than their existing MySQL db).

Comment: @ColinJack Sorry, I made a mistake about it. sqlite could not deal with text file.it just can load data form csv.